# Explaining Code in python object orientated classes

Tags: python, oop

I am currently taking a python course, I understand the lower part of this code please may someone explain what the upper half of the code does?
This is based on kettle brands as an example.

```py
class Kettle(object):
    def __init__(self, make, price):
        self.make = make
        self.price = price
        self.on = False


kenwood = Kettle("Kenwood", 8.99)
print(kenwood.make)
print(kenwood.price)

   

kenwood.price = 12.75
print(kenwood.price)
hamilton = Kettle("Hamiltion", 14.55)
print("Models: {} = {}, {} = {}".format(kenwood.make, kenwood.price, hamilton.make, hamilton.price))
```

Comment: can you share what you understand from the code, so other can help you to learn better

Comment: I understand every thing except what the first 5 lines of code do. I have a rough idea about the 3 of them but the first two I do not not have much understanding of.

Comment: The top half simply defines a class, or a custom type if you will. This class has three attributes, `make`, `price`, and `on`. When you create an instance of this class (an object), you call the constructor `Kettle("Kenwood", 8.99)`. Based on the definition of `init`, the object has `make` and `price` set to Kenwood and 8.99, respectively. The `self` part of the class is similar to a pointer to the object. It simply specifies that the assignment applies to the object, not a local variable. It's a simple as that.

Comment: @Ryan_Davies [python course tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php) go through this, you will understand better regarding what is class, why it is being used, what it represent and how to use it

Answer (score 1):

The class essentially creates a framework for making objects. So when making the "kenwood", it's creating a Kettle object, with the name as "Kenwood" and price at 8.99. This can be done recursively to create as many kettle objects as you needed, which is very helpful.

Comment: Recursive is not the appropriate term to use here. The ability to instantiate a class does not involve recursion.

Answer (score 1):

the `class` portion of the code defines a class. This class/object has 2 attributes that the user defines when they create the object, and one which is defaulting to False. The `def __init__(self, make, price):` function is known as the constructor. It tells python how to create the object and with what values when you say `kenwood = Kettle(...)`
So when you create a new kettle it will use the values you tell it and set those to the attributes of the function.

In this code you have defined the class `Kettle` and created two Kettle objects with the attributes passed to the `Kettle` object as price and make.

Hope this explanation helps.